# Easel.js stage.clear() not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

Pretty simple concept but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
stage.clear();
stage.update();
```

Simple stuff -- nothing happens. The docs aren't helping.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
stage.removeAllChildren();
stage.update();
```

Comment: Yeah, it may not be obvious at first that once you add a child to the stage, they're there from now on; they're drown at every update().  The idea is that you add a child once, then just update its position when needed.  If you are removing and then adding the same objects during each loop, you are probably doing a lot of extra work.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I spent all day searching for a solution like this.

Answer (score 2):

if you have just one child of shape on that stage and dont want use removeallchildren, you can do this:

```
myshape.graphics.clear();
stage.update();
```

if more than one, then loop its children.