# Improve perfomance of angular application which contains create js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, createjs

I am using [CreateJs](http://createjs.com/) for drawing world map and clearing that points using

```
stage.removeAllChildren();
stage.update();
```

methods in my angular application.

Those methods are working but after using the maps for some time my application performance is decreasing drastically. Is there any way to make the performance better.

Checked this
[Easel.js stage.clear() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056076/easel-js-stage-clear-not-working)

Comment: Removing children will prevent the stage from drawing content, but are you cleaning up other things? References, event listeners, tickers, etc?

Comment: @Lanny After removing children i am able to draw content.But after using it a while its perfomance is decreasing.Can u tell me how to clean up other things.

Comment: It is very dependent on your code and what you are doing. Have you tried profiling the app?

Comment: `@Lanny` after removing all eventListeners on stage it is giving better perfomance. Thanks for your solution.